# css selector with pattern

Tags: html, css

I have a styling to write in such way that it should cover most elements that follow the pattern.
There is a default style sheet that covers the class attribute.

I have this in my page:

```
<label class="control-label" id="selectror_test_1" data-original-title="" title="">
      some value
    </label>
```

I am trying to write the following :

```
[id^='selectror_test_']{
    color:red
}
```

The problem is the default style sheet has

```
.control-label{
    color:black
}
```

The pattern based style that I am trying to write is not overriding the default style applied.

Comment: Just make your selector more specific. E.g. `body  [id^='selectror_test_']`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this override by default css.

1. we can use !important to override. But that stricts to apply default css in some scenario (not recommended always)
2. or the best option to use prefix as a css class, as mentioned below -

   .control-label[id^='selectror_test_']{
   color:red
   }

Comment: Don't just go for the points—try to create a well-explained, useful answer that benefits the community. Otherwise, answers like this are better suited as comments.

Comment: I actually wanted to add comment, however dont have access yet :)